# Notificação para sinalização?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso

Eu acho que seria muito útil ao você sinalizar uma pergunta você receber uma notificação se essa sinalização foi útil ou não, e mostrar o que os moderadores do SOPT fizeram quanto à pergunta.

Comment: Você pode ver isso aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/24529

Comment: O link que o @jbueno achou fica meio escondido no perfil. Concordo que deveria gerar notificação, principalmente nas primeiras sinalizações.

Comment: Eu acho que, tendo no perfil isso, não seria necessário. Sei que  o recurso parece útil, mas é algo que pode ser facilmente consultado no perfil. @bfavaretto eu nem sabia que tinha isso no perfil, mas na semana passada quando pensei  o mesmo que o OP, encontrei facilmente lá. Não está assim tão escondido, é só mexer que encontra, alias, muita coisa do site é manuseando mais que se acha.

Comment: Eu também não sabia da existência dessa página, ainda acho um bom recurso para colocar na caixa de entrada.